# Wordpress add_image_size crop makes super bad quality

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to resize images in size 300x175, but the result is with super bad quality (the original image is with good quality).

The code I use is:

`add_image_size( 'saveti-home-thumb', 300, 175, true);`

I tried to disable the WordPress compression by adding:

`add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 100;});` in `functions.php`,

but still no result.

This is the original image: https://saveti.bg/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/meteora-scenery.jpg
This is the image after the compression: https://saveti.bg/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/meteora-scenery-300x175.jpg

As you can see the quality is super ruined. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it may be some factors:
One is something that happens whenever you need to crop images in cases where they don't follow the proportions of the photo.
The other is when an image is not in the rgb default.
And yet another seems like this has always happened in WP and hasn't been fixed yet

Links for you to read about the items I commented quickly.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/images-lose-quality-after-wp-resize-even-with-the-jpeg-quality-filter-at-100/
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/301710/image-quality-thumbnail-compression-in-wordpress

While this still doesn't have a good solution, my suggestion is to use thumbnails with crop-free images only with resizing by changing the current function code to:

```
 add_image_size( 'saveti-home-thumb', 300, 175, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. Hoped there is a better solution. I wanted the crop because of page speed, I want to serve the image with the exact size that is needed.

Comment: I cannot say this is a solution

Answer (score 0):

For Image Croping there is one good Plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Add this Plugin in your WordPress. Add the Image size that you want in `functions.php`.

```
add_image_size( 'saveti-home-thumb', 300, 175, true);
```

After that Regenerate all Images in

> Tools > Regenerate Thumbnails

After that call image with this parameter `saveti-home-thumb`. Like

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( int|WP_Post $post = null, string|array $size = 'saveti-home-thumb' )
```